# Using abstract classes as argument for function in C++

Tags: c++, class, abstract

I have a simple interface that provides Visitor pattern for graphs in DFS

```
class DFSVisitor {
public:
    virtual void enterVertex(DirectedGraph::VertexIndex vertex) = 0;
    virtual void leaveVertex(DirectedGraph::VertexIndex vertex) = 0;
    virtual void checkEdge(DirectedGraph::VertexIndex vertex, DirectedGraph::VertexIndex to) = 0;
};
```

And I got function that uses instance of mentioned class:

```
void dfs(VertexIndex vertex, std::vector<bool>& used, DFSVisitor& visitor) const {
    //some code
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting compile time error:

```
error c2259 cannot instantiate abstract class
```

I understand that I can just put some easy implementation into this class, even empty body would help, but I need to have this class abstract due to review conditions.

So how could I avoid this problem?

**Update:**
Code of VertexIndex:

```
typedef size_t VertexIndex;
```

Added to clarify code above.

**Update**
Thanks to everyone, I recognized the problem.
In function definition I needed only to change from reference to pointer

```
void dfs(VertexIndex vertex, std::vector<bool>& used, DFSVisitor* visitor) const {
    //some code
}
```

Because I can't work with reference of abstract class, only with pointer this code would. work.

Comment: Is VertexIndex abstract too? If not, can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: The compiler error you get is **not** due to the reference parameter. The reference parameter is perfectly fine, since you don't create an instance of the class. Or your code is different from the one shown. Could you perhaps check whether you are really passing by reference? Or accidentally create an object of that class type somewhere?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted, it should not result in this error. Please post a minimal piece of code that we can test-compile that reproduces that error.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? Perhaps you are inadvertently copying the DFSVisitor inside the function body?

Comment: Your reviewer is correct. That compiler error is telling you something important - somewhere, somehow, you are attempting to copy the argument

Comment: _'Because I can't work with reference of abstract class'_ That's not true, you can well use references to abstract classes?!? You just cannot use them to make copies.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's interesting, but I didn't copy this visitor - just used it as a reference. Are there any other possible problems?

Comment: @htzfun You actually don't show how you're really instantiating something you're going to pass to the `dfs()` function. Also did you try something like `DFSVisitor tempvar = visitor;` inside this function? Then you should change that to `DFSVisitor& tempvar = visitor;`. A reference can be used equally good as a pointer for this case.

Comment: @htzfun Edited. If you really want to close a question, flag mods for deletion. Otherwise you cannot directly delete it as long there are answers and you have not enough reputation.

Comment: "but I didn't copy this visitor". Your error message references some line number. Look at that line. It's the place you are making a copy. If you don't understand why a copy is made at that line, ask why a copy is made at that line. Don't forget to quote the line.

Comment: @n.m. It points to definition of the function dfs, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: This can happen if your *definition* uses `DFSVisitor` and not `DFSVisitor&` as it should. That's why I'm telling you to **quote the line**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that I can just put some easy implementation into this class ...

You can always work with a reference to the abstract class (`DFSVisitor`), but you cannot create an instance of that abstract class.

To provide instances have a derived class with an implementation

```
 class SomeVisitor : public DFSVisitor {
 public:
    virtual void enterVertex(DirectedGraph::VertexIndex vertex) {
        // Your implementation ...
    }
    virtual void leaveVertex(DirectedGraph::VertexIndex vertex) {
        // Your implementation ...
    }
    virtual void checkEdge
                  ( DirectedGraph::VertexIndex vertex
                  , DirectedGraph::VertexIndex to
                  )  {
        // Your implementation ...
    }
};
```

To pass it to your `dfs()` function write some code like

```
SomeVisitor visitor;
std::vector<bool> used;
dfs(5,used,visitor);
```

As for your question from the comment how to make the implementation class abstract

```
class SomeVisitor : public DFSVisitor {
protected:
    SomeVisitor() {} // <<< Force this class to be used from inherited classes
                     //     only.
};
```

and pass an instance of that one to the `dfs()` function call, but I doubt that was what your reviewer meant. It looks you're already on a good way fulfilling this requirement with your `DFSVisitor` abstract class.

Take care in the implementation of your `dfs()` method not to try creating value objects of the abstract class like e.g.

```
 void dfs
        ( VertexIndex vertex
        , std::vector<bool>& used
        , DFSVisitor& visitor) const {
     //some code
     DFSVisitor tempVisitor1 = visitor; // Such will lead to a compiler error
                                       // as you have
     // Use a reference instead
     DFSVisitor& tempVisitor2 = visitor; // Compiles fine
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but my reviewer wants me not to do this. Firstly, I got class that you described, but than he wanted me to change it to abstract.

Comment: @htzfun To do so, leave out one of the virtual or provide a `protected` constructor (see my edit). Anyway to pass something to the `dfs()` function, it must be an instance of some class derived from this interface. You simply cannot instantiate abstract classes, that's what your compiler message tells you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is passed by reference. Should be fine even if an abstract base class, as long as an instance of a derived class is supplied

Comment: @harmic Did I tell anything different?

Comment: You are telling OP to avoid the problem by making the class non abstract. That should not be necessary and in fact is probably masking the true problem.

Comment: @harmic _'by making the class non abstract'_ That's not true, I well preserved the abstract class. I told him to create an instatiable derived class to use it with the code expecting an abstract class reference.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, your solution suggest that, there is problem with OP's current code, but it should not, at-least not with the posted code. The problem lies somewhere else. passing reference to abstract class can not be a problem itself.

Comment: @RakibulHasan _'passing reference to abstract class can not be a problem itself.'_ I never state such?!? Just vice versa, have a look at my other comments in this thread.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, you have not said it, but your solution does not solve the actual problem( which is yet unknown), and rather will hide it.

Comment: @RakibulHasan THX for the sugesstions, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @htzfun Check my updates. I hope this clarifies a bit. Otherwise provide more context to your question please!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are passing `VertexIndex` by value, which involves object construction. Since the class is abstract, you can't do this.

Pass it by reference and it should work fine.

Comment: VertexIndex is a typedef for `size_t`.

Comment: But you gave me the idea of problem. Thanks. I upvoted.